# #selector(delete(_:)) crash in uitextfield swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

Whenever i type any text in `uitextfield` and i long press on that text and select on `delete` then it crashes. On crash it shows "**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[App_Name.HomeVC delete:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14e18ba00'**" . How do i fix this crash issue. Below is the swift code.

```
    class HomeVC: UIViewController{
    @IBOutlet weak var txtSearch: UITextField!
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
self.txtSearch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.txtChanged(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
@objc func txtChanged(_ sender : UITextField){
        print(txtSearch.text!)}
}
    override public func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
            if action == #selector(copy(_:)) || action == #selector(paste(_:)) || action == #selector(delete(_:)) || action == #selector(cut(_:))
                {
                    return true
                } else if action == Selector(("_lookup:")) || action == Selector(("_share:")) || action == Selector(("_define:")) {
                    return false
                }
                return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
            }
    }
```

Comment: there is a wrong } at :  print(txtSearch.text!)} ? is this just a typo ?

Comment: @PtitXav it is just a typo, the main problem is delete

Comment: You are returning `true` to indicate that your view controller can handle the `delete` action, but your view controller doesn't implement a `delete` function, so you get a crash.

Comment: @Paulw11 So what is the solution to solve this ?

Comment: If you code that the view controller can perform some action you have to add the corresponding code in the view controller that is functions delete,... for which you return true.

Comment: @PtitXav what i did `action == #selector(delete(textDelete))` `@objc func textDelete(){
        txtSearch.text = ""
    }` still it is getting error "Argument of '#selector' does not refer to an '@objc' method, property, or initializer" Is this correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the delete function :

```
class HomeVC: UIViewController{
    @IBOutlet weak var txtSearch: UITextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.txtSearch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.txtChanged(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
    }

    @objc func txtChanged(_ sender : UITextField){
        print(txtSearch.text!)
    }


    override func delete(_ sender: Any?) {
        txtSearch.text = ""
    }

    override public func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        if action == #selector(copy(_:)) || action == #selector(paste(_:)) || action == #selector(delete(_:)) || action == #selector(cut(_:))
            {
                return true
            } else if action == Selector(("_lookup:")) || action == Selector(("_share:")) || action == Selector(("_define:")) {
                return false
            }
            return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
        }
    }
```